# {}.toString() Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, tostring

when I try it in chrome dev tools, it shows 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`
However if when it assign to **a**:

```
var a={}.toString(); 
a //[object Object]
```

what caused the difference?

Comment: `({}).toString()`

Answer (score 3):

> what caused the difference?

The state the parser is in. By default, the parser is in a state where it expects a *statement*. So in your example in the console, the `{` looks like the opening of a block to it, not the beginning of an object initializer. (You can also give it an expression at that point, because JavaScript has the concept of the *ExpressionStatement*, which is a statement consisting entirely of an expression.)

But in your `var a={}.toString();` code, the `{}.toString()` appears on the right-hand side of an assigment, where the parser is expecting an *expression*, not a statement. So the `{` starts an object initializer.

If you do something to make the parser expect an expression instead, it'll work in the console too:

```
({}).toString(); // "[object Object]"
```

or

```
+{}.toString(); // NaN, because the `+` tries to turn `[object Object]` into a number and fails
```

Answer (score 2):

When you aren't in expression context (as is triggered by being on the right hand side of an assignment, for instance) then `{}` is [a block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and not an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is captured first and interpreted as a block, which has no `.toString` method to call.

If you wrap the object literal in parens, like `({}).toString()`, then it works as expected.

This is because of the parsing rule priorities and the `{}` tokens being overloaded to be both object and block delimiters.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fixed (I was working on the edit but got lost browsing the spec :( ).

Answer (score 0):

The parser is interpreting the `{}` as a code block. You can make it parse correctly by surrounding the braces with parentheses:

```
({}).toString();
```